# Conjugate gradient and the eigenvectors corresponding to the large eigenvalues

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, eigenvalues, eigenvector

I am working on an optimization problem (for example, conjugate gradient) to solve $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. I can understand that the CG (conjugate gradient) has better performance when the matrix $A$ has a smaller conditioner number. But I am wondering is there a relationship between the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest few eigenvalues and the first few update directions of the CG? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

(This question is also posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046456/conjugate-gradient-and-the-eigenvectors-corresponding-to-the-large-eigenvalues).)

Comment: crossposted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046456/conjugate-gradient-and-the-eigenvectors-corresponding-to-the-large-eigenvalues --- please don't do that, in particular not without disclosing it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have modified it.